# I'm using Flutter to develop an app, and I'm having a problem with not being able to jump to a page

Tags: flutter

I'm using Flutter to develop an app, and I'm having a problem with not being able to jump to a page.

```
GestureDetector(
child: textField,
 onTap: () {
   showSearch(context: context, delegate: PatientSearchBarDelegate(contextFather: this.context));
      },)
```

Clicking on it does not redirect you to the corresponding page.
Here are the logs clicked.

```
The following StackOverflowError was thrown while handling a gesture:
Stack Overflow

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Navigator.push (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1793:3)
#1      Navigator.push (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1795:22)
#2      Navigator.push (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1795:22)
#3      Navigator.push (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1795:22)
#4      Navigator.push (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1795:22)
...
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#61c88
  debugOwner: GestureDetector
  state: ready
  won arena
  finalPosition: Offset(91.0, 117.0)
  finalLocalPosition: Offset(44.0, 25.0)
  button: 1
  sent tap down
```

Comment: do you want to navigate to one page to another?

Comment: Yes. I want to use the showSearch method to go to the search page

Comment: why don't you do it with Navigator?

Comment: I want to use the showSearch method to go to the search page

Comment: you need to share your code as well to get better answer.